# How to create an auto increment primary key in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following create statement for a SQLite database table.  What do I add to this statement to make the ID column auto-increment?

```
CREATE TABLE [Employee] ([Id] bigint NOT NULL , [FirstName] varchar(2147483647) NULL , [LastName] nvarchar(2147483647) NULL, [StartDate] Datetime NULL, [TermDate] datetime NULL, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_master_PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]));
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You would use the `autoincrement` keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    Id integer primary key autoincrement,
    . . .
```

However, you might want to review the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) to see if this is really necessary.  SQLite includes a `rowid` which often has sufficient functionality.